# Microsoft graph get lists in sites returns 401

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to list all lists in a sharepoint site using this Microsoft Graph query, it returns me an 401 error. But reading a list works fine.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "6929864e-9d14-4911-9d7e-d0a29259e05f",
        "date": "2017-06-21T21:00:15"
    }
}
```

}

- Does not work: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists
- Work: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a 401 response indicates that the information the server needs to authenticate your API request is either missing from the request or present but somehow invalid. I'd suggest that you:

1) Verify that the **Authorization** header is present in the request that fails.

2) If present, then verify that the contents of the **Authorization** header in the request that fails is ***identical*** to the contents of the **Authorization** header in the request that succeeds.

If you're sending the exact same **Authorization** header in both requests, then I wouldn't expect the server to return a 401 response for one operation but not the other. (If it were a permissions issue -- i.e., the user has rights to perform operation-A but not operation-B, then I'd expect the server to return a 403 Forbidden response for operation-B -- not a 401 Unauthorized response.)

---

**Update (some additional thoughts)**

It looks like both operations require one of these two access scopes:

- Sites.Read.All
- Sites.ReadWrite.All

You should verify that the token you're specifying in the `Authorization` header of the failing request has at least one of these scopes (although as I said earlier, I'd expect the server to return 403 if you didn't have the proper access scope).

Also, if you obtained the access token via OAuth without a user providing authorization, then perhaps the information in this answer might be helpful: [How to use OAuth when there is no user delegation? -- Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464831/how-to-use-oauth-when-there-is-no-user-delegation-microsoft-graph-api/44475072#44475072). In the scenario that post describes, the server was returning a 401 response because the developer hadn't explicitly obtained administrator consent for the operation they were attempting to perform.

Comment: @Nico -- I've updated my answer to add additional info.  Have you made any progress with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try again? This (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists) seems to be working now.